# Can I store persistent data in a Rhomobile application?

Tags: rhomobile

Can I store persistent data in a Rhomobile application **without** a license throughout multiple times I turn the app on or off?

All I am looking to store is a simple coordinate, two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer, I work for Motorola Solutions, that builds the RhoMobile Suite.*

The Open Source Rhodes framework, that is the core of the RhoMobile technology to build multi-platform applications, include everything that you need to [persist data con consumer OS](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom) (the license, it's needed only when targeting Windows Mobile, Windows CE and Big Windows).

take a look at [this image](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/rhoelements-introduction), that explain what you've in Rhodes (MIT license) and what addition you get with a RhoElements license.

Rhodes is available on [github](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes) on in the [RhoMobile Suite](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/rhomobile-suite) together with RhoElements, RhoConnect and RhoStudio.

~Pietro